# Use of is/are in sentences where you talk about two things - one singular and other plural

Tags: be

This recently came up when chatting with a colleague who moved companies. I asked "How **is** your manager and teammates?"

Later I thought if I should've used "How **are** your manager and teammates?"

Which one is correct?

Comment: Really it ought to be “are” since you are talking about more than one thing. Perhaps think about the form an answer to your question would take: “My manager and teammates ARE doing well, thank you.” (Contrast this by replacing ARE with IS).

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter that one is singular and the other is plural; it matters that the whole group of them are more than one person. "How are Nancy and Sakura?"